# Create a listener logic for a custom combobox

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a listener logic for a custom combo box that I have created that contains items with check boxes.

I was not able to proceed as I am not getting an idea on how to do it.

MainApplication.java

```
public class MainApplication extends Application{

 @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(), 450, 250);

        ComboBox<ComboBoxItemWrap<Person>> cb = new ComboBox<>();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ObservableList<ComboBoxItemWrap<Person>> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new ComboBoxItemWrap<>(new Person("A", "12-Aug-1994")),
                new ComboBoxItemWrap<>(new Person("B", "13-Aug-1994")),
                new ComboBoxItemWrap<>(new Person("C", "14-Aug-1994"))
                );

        cb.setCellFactory( c -> {
            ListCell<ComboBoxItemWrap<Person>> cell = new ListCell<ComboBoxItemWrap<Person>>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(ComboBoxItemWrap<Person> item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (!empty) {
                        final CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(item.toString());
                        cb.selectedProperty().bind(item.checkProperty());
                        setGraphic(cb);
                    }
                }
            };

            cell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, event -> {
                cell.getItem().checkProperty().set(!cell.getItem().checkProperty().get());
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                cb.getItems().filtered( f-> f!=null).filtered( f-> f.getCheck()).forEach( p -> {
                    sb.append("; "+p.getItem());
                });
                final String string = sb.toString();
                cb.setPromptText(string.substring(Integer.min(2, string.length())));
            });

            return cell;
        });

        cb.setItems(options);

        VBox root = (VBox) scene.getRoot();

        Button bt = new Button("test");

        bt.setOnAction(event -> {
            cb.getItems().filtered( f -> f.getCheck()).forEach( item -> System.out.println(item.getItem()));
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(cb, bt);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
 }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

}
```

ComboBoxItemWrap.java

```
public class ComboBoxItemWrap<T> {
    private BooleanProperty check = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    private ObjectProperty<T> item = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

ComboBoxItemWrap() {
}

ComboBoxItemWrap(T item) {
    this.item.set(item);
}

ComboBoxItemWrap(T item, Boolean check) {
    this.item.set(item);
    this.check.set(check);
}

public BooleanProperty checkProperty() {
    return check;
}

public Boolean getCheck() {
    return check.getValue();
}

public void setCheck(Boolean value) {
    check.set(value);
}

public ObjectProperty<T> itemProperty() {
    return item;
}

public T getItem() {
    return item.getValue();
}

public void setItem(T value) {
    item.setValue(value);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return item.getValue().toString();
}

}
```

Person.java

```
public class Person {
    private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty birthday = new SimpleStringProperty();

public Person() {
}

public Person(String name, String birthday) {
    setNameValue(name);
    setBirthdayValue(birthday);
}

public StringProperty getNameProperty() {
    return name;
}

public String getNameValue() {
    return name.getValue();
}

public void setNameValue(String value) {
    name.setValue(value);
}

public StringProperty getBirthdayProperty() {
    return birthday;
}

public String getBirthdayValue() {
    return birthday.getValue();
}

public void setBirthdayValue(String value) {
    birthday.setValue(value);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getNameValue()+" ("+getBirthdayValue()+")";
}

}
```

In the output application, a list of items with check boxes will get populated. On selection of any number of entries in the list, the entry name gets populated on the combo box itself separated by a ';'. Now I want my back end code to listen and identify the entries that have been selected in order to perform further operations.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to reinvent the wheel. Consider using [ControlsFX `CheckComboBox`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/CheckComboBox.html).

That being said there are several problems in the code:

1. You never update the property on a selection of the `CheckBox`. This can be easily fixed by using bidirectional bindings.
2. Since the `ComboBox` popup is closed, the `CheckBox` is no longer armed at the time the `MOUSE_RELEASED` event is triggered. this is a prerequesite for the `selected` state of the `CheckBox` changing though. Modifying the skin allows you to change this behaviour.
3. You use `ObservableList.filtered` to create `FilteredList`s that you throw away immediately afterwards. You also create a filtered list of a filtered list in the `MOUSE_RELEASED` event filter. This is not wrong per se, but you're creating an expensive object there without the need to do so: simply get a stream there. This is a much more lightweight way to filter a list, if the result is only needed once. Use `filtered`/`FilteredList` only if you need an `ObservableList` that contains elements from another `ObservableList` and that is automatically updated.

Also note that there is a way to make an `ObservableList` trigger update changes on a change of a property: Use the `observableArrayList` method taking an extractor as parameter.

This is how you could rewrite your code to make it work:

```
VBox root = new VBox();
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 250);

ComboBox<ComboBoxItemWrap<Person>> cb = new ComboBox<>();

ObservableList<ComboBoxItemWrap<Person>> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList(item -> new Observable[] {item.checkProperty()});
options.addAll(
        new ComboBoxItemWrap<>(new Person("A", "12-Aug-1994")),
        new ComboBoxItemWrap<>(new Person("B", "13-Aug-1994")),
        new ComboBoxItemWrap<>(new Person("C", "14-Aug-1994")));

cb.setCellFactory(c -> new ListCell<ComboBoxItemWrap<Person>>() {
        private final CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(ComboBoxItemWrap<Person> item, boolean empty) {
            ComboBoxItemWrap<Person> oldItem = getItem();
            if (oldItem != null) {
                // remove old binding
                cb.selectedProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldItem.checkProperty());
            }

            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                cb.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(item.checkProperty());
                cb.setText(item.toString());
                setGraphic(cb);
            }
        }
    });

// make sure popup remains open
ComboBoxListViewSkin<ComboBoxItemWrap<Person>> skin = new ComboBoxListViewSkin<>(cb);
skin.setHideOnClick(false);

cb.setSkin(skin);

cb.setItems(options);
cb.promptTextProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() ->
    options.stream().filter(ComboBoxItemWrap::getCheck).map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("; ")), options));
```

Note that if you want the popup to be closed after (de)selecting a checkbox, you could simply add a event filter for `MOUSE_RELEASED` for the checkbox that calls `cb.arm()` instead of modifying the skin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am not able to implement it. Currently the method setHideOnClick works for type ComboBoxListViewSkin<ComboBox<T>> but in my case it is ComboBoxListViewSkin<ComboBoxItemWrap<T>>. I am not sure how to handle this type mismatch.

Comment: @AmitDRoy The type parameters for the skin and the `ComboBox` match. Since I consider it unlikely that your `ComboBox` contains items of type `ComboBox`, `ComboBoxListView<T>` should be used with a `ComboBox<T>`.